# Customizing the logging in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The default production logging in Rails 4 is pretty verbose, and each request is no longer separated with a line break.  Is there an easy way to restore the old format for production logging?

This is what I currently see:

```
I, [2013-07-08T16:12:41.217715 #14008]  INFO -- : Processing by MarketingController#index as HTML
I, [2013-07-08T16:12:41.223885 #14008]  INFO -- :   Rendered marketing/index.html.erb within layouts/marketing (3.7ms)
```